# Signal Sigabrt error, tableView Rows in Section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I tried to create a static TableView with 3 different sections, each with another amount of rows:

```
let numberOfRowsAtSection:[Int] = [5,4,3]
```

And this is my numberOfRowsinSection function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var rows: Int = 0
    
    if section < numberOfRowsAtSection.count {
        rows = numberOfRowsAtSection[section]
    }
    return rows
}

         override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)



    return cell
}
```

But every time I try to execute this it I get error

> Signal Sigabrt
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

If I replace `return rows` with `return 0` the error is fixed. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: add your numberOfSections implementation please, and also the cellForRow implementation

Comment: Post your `cellForRowAt` function. Also, post full description of the error you're getting.

Comment: Actually if you are using a **static** table view you don't need the dynamic delegate and data source methods at all since all cells are accessible via outlets and actions.

Comment: I added it mag_zbc

Comment: Which line of code exactly is causing the error?

Comment: can you post your `numberOfSections` method?